# Regarding code coverage tool in VS 2010 for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to test code coverage of C++ code in VS 2010. I have following questions regarding this:

1. What are steps we have to follow to test code coverage of C++ code in VS 2010.
2. Can code coverage be performed on unmanaged C++?
3. Can code coverage tool provided in VS 2010 for C++ be used with CPP unit, if yes what are the steps we have to follow?

Kindly request to help with an example if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
http://open-tube.com/10-code-coverage-tools-c-c/